Which graphs can be represented as adjacencies in a rectangular subdivision?
The TL;DR version:

Is there a simple characterization of graphs representable by adjacencies of a subdivision of a rectangle into smaller rectangles?

Now the longer version:
I am working on a program that draws treemaps, visualizations of hierarchical data that work by subdividing a larger rectangle into smaller rectangles based on size. For example, here's a treemap showing the number of BS, MS, and PhD graduates from a CS department:

One step of drawing treemaps is to assign colors to each top-level subdivision of the rectangle. Ideally, I'd like to do this in a way that (1) doesn't assign any two adjacent rectangles the same color and (2) requires as few colors as possible. In the example above, the top-level subdivision consists of the three colored rectangles, and three colors suffices.
Figuring out how to do this in as few colors as possible got me thinking about this as a graph problem: there's a node for each top-level subdivision of the rectangle, and an edge between any two rectangles whose borders overlap (excluding corners). I then want to find the chromatic number of this graph and an associated minimal coloring.
It's clear from the construction that this graph will be a planar graph, and thus at most four colors are needed. It's also possible to exhibit rectangular subdivisions that require four colors, such as this one here derived from the Moser spindle:

However, I don't believe it's possible to embed $K_4$ into a rectangular subdivision, as that would require four mutually adjacent rectangles.
So in one sense, I've been able to show that four colors are necessary, and I'm fairly sure that we can't embed $K_4$, so I'm fairly sure I'm looking at a family of graphs that is a strict subset of the planar graphs, but I don't know what those graphs are. Perhaps this family of graphs has a nice structure that leads to a simple 4-coloring algorithm?

See https://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~felsner/Paper/geom-rep.pdf Theorem 2.2 and the references that follow. Perhaps one of these will satisfy your curiosity.
